# Selenium loop, table missing first row and last column

Tags: selenium, html-table

I am trying to get the table shown in the url below. But the result is missing the first row (2021-11) and the last column (净投放(亿)). What have I done wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get('http://www.chinamoney.com.cn/chinese/hb/')

rws = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")
r = len(rws)

cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//thead/tr/td")
c = len(cols)

element = []
row = []
for i in range(1,r):
    for j in range(1,c):
        d=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr["+str(i)+"]/td["+str(j)+"]").text
        row.append(d)

element.append(row)
driver.close()

element
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `for loop starts` from `index 1`, the element at `index 0` is skipped.

And the last two rows of the table are empty.

To get the all the values from the table, try like below:

```
driver.get("http://www.chinamoney.com.cn/chinese/hb/")

# Scroll Down to footer so that the all the data in the table is accessible to selenium

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",driver.find_element_by_id("main-page-foot"))

# Collect the table rows using - xpath "//table//tr", in the variable rows
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr") # rows is a list of webelements - rows of the table(tr tags of the table).
element = []

# Iterate over the list

for row in rows:
    # Get the data inside a row. Columns is also a list of webelements - "td" tags of that particular "tr"

    columns = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td") # Put a dot in the xpath to get an element from an element. 

    list_row = [] # Temporary list to store values of td tags
    for col in columns: 
        list_row.append(col.text) # Append all the td tags values 
    element.append(list_row) # Append the list of td tag values
print(element)
```

```
[['日期', '投放量(亿)', '回笼量(亿)', '净投放(亿)'], ['2021-11', '2200', '12200', '-10000'], ['2021-10', '13900', '12300', '1600'], ['2021-09', '11800', '5900', '5900'], ['2021-08', '4200', '2600', '1600'], ['2021-07', '2600', '3200', '-600'], ['2021-06', '3100', '2100', '1000'], ['2021-05', '1900', '2000', '-100'], ['2021-04', '2200', '2100', '100'], ['2021-03', '2400', '2500', '-100'], ['2021-02', '8300', '11440', '-3140'], ['2021-01', '10740', '12450', '-1710'], ['2020-12', '9150', '8900', '250'], ['2020-11', '17550', '17200', '350'], ['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '']]
```

Comment: Thanks. For me this response just returns an empty list. Have I missed something?

Comment: @paul -  Have updated the code. Scroll down to footer and then try to extract the details

Comment: thanks very much. That works. But can you explain for me what it does?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use ranges from 0, not from 1
2. Also you should add some wait to let the page fully loaded before accessing the tables content.
   I will add a simple delay here but t's better to use explicit waits.
   Please see if the following code work better for you:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get('http://www.chinamoney.com.cn/chinese/hb/')

time.sleep(5)
rws = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")
r = len(rws)

cols = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//thead/tr/td")
c = len(cols)

element = []
row = []
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        d=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr["+str(i)+"]/td["+str(j)+"]").text
        row.append(d)

element.append(row)
driver.close()

element
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can't make this response work, getting the response NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //tr[0]/td[0]